# create a trigger that adds a field to +5 and creates the total in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new and I'm not so good with the triggers, I place the tables and figure out how to create this sum

```
-- Table `databasestreaming`.`tipologiaabbonamento`
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `databasestreaming`.`tipologiaabbonamento` (
  `idtipologiaabbonamento` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `piano abbonamento` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dispositivi` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Risoluzione` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Prezzo` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtipologiaabbonamento`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `databasestreaming`.`abbonamento`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `databasestreaming`.`abbonamento` (
  `idabbonamento` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data attivazione` DATE NULL,
  `data termine` DATE NULL,
  `Sport` ENUM("Si", "No") NULL,
  `cliente_idcliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `tipologiaabbonamento_idtipologiaabbonamento` INT NOT NULL,
  `Prezzo_finale` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idabbonamento`, `cliente_idcliente`, `tipologiaabbonamento_idtipologiaabbonamento`),
  INDEX `fk_abbonamento_cliente_idx` (`cliente_idcliente` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_abbonamento_tipologiaabbonamento1_idx` (`tipologiaabbonamento_idtipologiaabbonamento` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_abbonamento_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cliente_idcliente`)
    REFERENCES `databasestreaming`.`cliente` (`idcliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_abbonamento_tipologiaabbonamento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tipologiaabbonamento_idtipologiaabbonamento`)
    REFERENCES `databasestreaming`.`tipologiaabbonamento` (`idtipologiaabbonamento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I would like that when the user selects from enum Si with Sport, the trigger will take the price from the type of subscription (three types of subscriptions that will choose the user) and add the type of subscription chosen to the eventual or not of the sport choice, if yes, then we add +5 if instead it chooses no, in the final price I would like it to simply report the price of the chosen subscription

Comment: "create a trigger that adds a field to +5 and creates the total in another table" sounds like a clear "violation" off normalisation rules where you never store calculated values.

Comment: so I can not do in the field price_final with the choice of sport enum 'Si' (+5) + price type subscription?

Comment: BEGIN
  IF Sport = 'Si' THEN 
     UPDATE abbonamento 
     SET Prezzo_finale = (SELECT Prezzo from tipologiaabbonamento where tipologiaabbonamento_idtipologiaabbonamento + 5)
        END IF;END

I tried this way, but I do not know if it's correct, however it gives me syntax error

Comment: @Vik- Before going into details first see the usage of triggers.Show us what queries you have tried to serve your purpose,then only we will be able to help you.